# Python wheel installed successfully but unable to import modules

Tags: python-3.8, python-wheel

I have a `myFunction.pyd` file which I have tested to make sure that modules defined internally are accessible.

I then created a wheel file `myFunction-1.0-py3-none-any.whl`

Finally using `cmd` prompt I installed the wheel file. I can then also see the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Python38\Lib\site-packages\myFunction-1.0.dist-info
```

However, when I do the following `import myFunction as mf` it gives error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myFunction'`

Only thing I can think of is I didn't do anything with the `pyd` file that I had generated. Do I need to also move that file to some location?

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: it's not a coding error, its problem with process of creating wheel

Comment: But how can we solve it without looking at `setup.py` and all other package files?

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I have the same issue.